# Help with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Whatever string is given I have to see if there is exactly one space after and before `=`, If it is more than one space in either side I have to reduce that to one and if there is none, I have to insert one.

How should I do that ? String can contain anything.

Thanks

Comment: Good answers below. You might also considering using `/\s*=\s*/gm` in case you want all whitespace characters to be converted to single space characters in your expression

Comment: Thanks all, all the answers are right. Can give only one answer the right sign :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
str = str.replace(/ *= */g, " = ");
```

This will replace all `=` characters regardless of how many spaces it is surrounded by. The `*` quantifier will match as most spaces as possible while allowing even no spaces at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var out = in.replace(/ *= */g, " = ");
```

Basically just replace zero or more instances of a space with a space and you get both desired results. If zero, then you get one. If more than one, you get one.

Answer (score 1):

Make the following replacement:

```
s = s.replace(/ *= */g, ' = ')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myString.replace(/\s*=\s*/g, " = ")
```

will do the same as other given answers, but allow any type of space characters to be replaced (spaces, tabs, etc.).